# Bootstrap: Change Div Order for 3 Columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to order three columns using Bootstrap 3. 
I have the following columns on big screens:

```
-----------------------------
|       | Name              |
| Video |-------------------|
|       | Description       |
-----------------------------
```

I want them to stack like this for mobile:

```
-----------------------------
| Name                      |
-----------------------------
| Video                     |
-----------------------------
| Description               |
-----------------------------
```

I've been trying to stack them using push and pull, but I can only get them to stack like this on my desktop:

```
-----------------------------
|       | Name              |
| Video |--------------------
|       |
-----------------------------
        | Description       |
        ---------------------
```

I'm having trouble getting description to float up. Sounds like it's a simple problem but I'm having trouble thinking through it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post code to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have been using bootstrap's `col-*-push-*` and `col-*-pull-*` classes. The limitation they have is that, since they apply margins to achieve their effect, they can only move elements horizontally.

You can fix this using the `pull-right` class, which sets the float direction instead. A sample is shown below.

```css
div { color:white; }

#Name { background:red; height:50px; }
#Video { background:green; height:100px; }
#Description { background:blue; height:50px; }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="Name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right">Name</div>
<div id="Video" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">Video</div>
<div id="Description" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-right">Description</div>
```

Comment: Ugh! I I knew it was a super simple solution! Thank you that works perfectly. Yeah, the col-push and col-pull apply margins therefore they were not floating correctly.